# Unity3d: Delay between animation cycles

Tags: unity, 2d, animation

trying to create simple 360 rotation animation on 2d object but can't understand delay between animation cycles, please check youtube video with issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlLJLHvnkgo

Comment: It looks like you've given your rotation an ease in/out curve, so it slowly ramps into the rotation and slowly ramps out at the end - creating a lull at the loop-around point. What happens if you remove that ease and stick to a straight line in your animation editor?

Comment: sorry, don't understand, unity docs says animation curve is value in time, so Y curve axis is Z rotation angle value, how i can change it to to a straight line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your animation curves view, click & drag to select the keys representing the start and end of your rotation.

[image]

Right-click and choose Both Tangents -> Linear from the context menu.

This will change your rotation from one that has a slow start and finish (those rounded plateaus at the beginning and end of the curve) to one that proceeds at a consistent rate throughout (a straight line on the graph)

[image]